# How can I successfully to use limit() method with subqueries with Rails and SQL Server Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, tiny-tds

### Actual behavior

It seems that `limit()` doesn't add to the generated subquery which actually is a `Model::ActiveRecord_Relation`, instead tries an execution which throws the error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception table doesn't exists

### Code and how to get the issue

```
class Doc < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "D_docs"

  has_many :doc_dirs

  has_many :dirs, through: :doc_dirs

  default_scope -> { where(inactive: false, is_version_1: true)}

  scope :doc_collection, -> do
    str_sql = "
        (
          SELECT [D_docs].[fileType], [D_docs].[inactive], [D_docs].[isVisible]
          FROM [D_docs]
        ) [D_docs]
    "
    doc_collec = Doc.from(str_sql).limit(10)
    # byebug
    doc_collec
  end
end
```

On rails console if you add a debug between
`doc_collec = Doc.from(str_sql).limit(10)` and  `doc_collec`

running `doc_collec.to_sql` you will get:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: Table '( SELECT [D_docs].[fileType], [D_docs].[inactive], [D_docs].[isVisible] FROM [D_docs] ) [D_docs]' doesn't exist

it should be noted that `Doc.from(str_sql).to_sql` is giving: `SELECT [D_docs].* FROM ( SELECT [D_docs].[fileType], [D_docs].[inactive], [D_docs].[isVisible] FROM [D_docs] ) [D_docs]`

A correct and without errors of `Doc.from(str_sql).limit(10)` is working on older rails versions (6.1.7) and  SQL Server adapter version 6.x.x successfully generating the query:

```
SELECT [D_docs].* FROM ( SELECT [D_docs].[fileType], [D_docs].[inactive], [D_docs].[isVisible] FROM [D_docs] ) [D_docs] OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Also `Doc.from(str_sql).order(:pkid)` works as expected

The versions:

- **Rails version**: `7.1.2`
- **SQL Server adapter version**: `7.1.0`
- **TinyTDS version**: `2.1.5`

---

### UPDATE

Thanks to [@engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky)

After changing `doc_collec = Doc.from(str_sql).limit(10)` to

```
doc_collec = Doc.from(Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(Doc.select(:fileType,:inactive,:isVisible).arel, self.table_name))).limit(10)
```

I'm getting:

```
SELECT [D_docs].* FROM (SELECT [D_docs].[fileType], [D_docs].[inactive], [D_docs].[isVisible] FROM [D_docs]) [D_docs] ORDER BY [D_docs].[docName] ORDER BY [D_docs][pkid] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

which works (have to change the query); now I'd like to prevent the order by `[D_docs].[pkid]` if is possible, the reason not pkid is needed bc I'm planning to add an union query, how can I do it?

Comment: How can I successfully to use limit() method with subqueries in new Rails 7.1.2 and SQL Server adapter version: 7.1.0

Comment: The query with `OFFSET` isn't valid; to `OFFSET` first you **must** `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It's easy to disprove your hypothesis about `limit` in the console with `Doc.limit(1).class` To your code, and I really can't work out what you're trying to do, `from(sql)` will generate a `NameError`, and the only other thing I can imagine you meant to do there was `from(result)` which gives something close to the error you're reporting, but makes no sense at all.

Comment: Modified the code, you're right with from(sql)

The error is with subqueries similar I'm posting, I've run the ```Doc.limit(1)```and works but if you try ```Doc.from(' ( SELECT pkid, docName FROM [D_document] ) [D_document] ').limit(10).to_sql```
you will get the error

Btw ```Doc.from(' ( SELECT * FROM [D_doc] ) [D_doc] ').limit(10).class``` indeed returns ```Doc::ActiveRecord_Relation``` which I need for pagination applying later on

Keeping in mind my db SQLserver and versions (It works perfect with PostgreSql) I've tested on that DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your post I am making the following assumption (as it is the only way that SQL code be generated as stated)

```
class Doc < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "D_docs"
end
```

That being said we can construct your desired functionality as follows:

```
 scope :doc_collection, -> do
    Doc.from(
      Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(Doc.select(:docName,:docType).arel, self.table_name)
    ).order(:docName).limit(10)
  end
```

This will result in:

```
SELECT [D_docs].* FROM (SELECT [D_docs].[docName], [D_docs].[docType] FROM [D_docs]) [D_docs] ORDER BY [D_docs].[docName] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

**Note** by excluding the selection of the primary key you will not be able to relate this data to other associations such as `doc_dirs`, please ensure this is your explicit intention or simply add `pkid` to the select list above.

**Discourse**

Your question is unclear as to: (Answered in comments)

- What `[D_docs]` is, since it seems like it that table does not exist?

> **A**: [D_docs] is as you're using
>
> **Response**: You should probably add this to your post

- Why you need a subquery since you are selecting an entire table?

> **A**: The subquery actually is selecting specific values, [D_docs].docName and [D_docs].doctype and other values from associated tables (not worth mentioning)
>
> **Response**: This would have been beneficial context to the original post. Additionally the not worth mentioning is probably worth mentioning.

- How you intend to utilize this with an alias of `[D_docs]`?

> **A**: After your comment an alias seems to work but when the limit() method is added the query a order by [D_doc].[pkid] which is invalid bc the query only fetches docName and docType
>
> **Response**: You cannot have a limit without the order by because MSSQL Limit uses OFFSET and FETCH and needs to know how to order so it can offset consistently

Comment: Answering your question:

- What [D_docs] is, since it seems like it that table does not exist?
[D_docs] is as you're using

- Why you need a subquery since you are selecting an entire table?
The subquery actually is selecting specific values, [D_docs].docName and [D_docs].doctype and other values from associated tables (not worth mentioning)

- How you intend to utilize this with an alias of [D_docs]?
After your comment an alias seems to work but when the limit() method is added the query a order by [D_doc].[pkid] which is invalid bc the query only fetches docName and docType

Comment: it's generating the following:
```SELECT  [D_docs].* FROM (SELECT  [D_docs].* FROM [D_docs] ) [D_docs] ORDER BY [D_docs].[pkid] OFFSET 0 ROWS  FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY```

Comment: @Adrián in order to have a limit you must have an *order by*. I have updated my post given your new details. That being said excluding the primary key means this data cannot be used for relationships to things like `doc_dirs` so unless you have a reason to specifically exclude it I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: @Adrián as I mentioned you can't limit without order. If you need a union that's a whole different question.

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestions given by [@engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky) I was able to get the query working as expected, noticed also I've added the `.order('')` so  doing `doc_collec.to_sql` debugging before `doc_collec` it's returned the generated query:

```
SELECT [D_docs].* FROM (SELECT [D_docs].[docName], [D_docs].[docType] FROM[D_docs]) [D_docs] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

New modified scope:

```
scope :doc_collection, -> do
  doc_collec = Doc.from(
    Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(Doc.select(:fileType,:inactive,:isVisible).arel, self.table_name))
  ).order('').limit(10)
  # byebug
  doc_collec
end
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Have you confirmed that this actually works? As mentioned in the comments and in my post you cannot use OFFSET/FETCH without an ORDER BY clause See [Reference Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Yes I have. Actually the output query is from debugging process.

Comment: but does it work? I can output any query I want because Arel is just an AST assembler. This does not mean it is functional, also when you call this method look at the actual query that is generated. I will be willing to bet it adds an ORDER BY or you get an error because the SQL you posted is syntactically erroneous.